# Instantiation of chaincode tries to find chaincode in /usr/local/src/chaincode.js

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

Installation of chaincode works fine but if I try to instantiate the chaincode I get the following npm error from the peer:

```
> cc@1.0.0 start /usr/local/src
> node chaincode.js "--peer.address"        "peer0.MiddleMan.shippingcompany.com:9052"

 module.js:549
 throw err;
 ^

 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/src/chaincode.js'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
     at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! cc@1.0.0 start: `node chaincode.js "--peer.address" "peer0.MiddleMan.shippingcompany.com:9052"`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the cc@1.0.0 start script.
```

What I use for instantiation:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n cc -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "AND ('PharmaProducerMSP.peer','MiddleManMSP.peer', 'PharmacyMSP.peer')"
```

I don't quite understand why the peer is able to install the chaincode just fine but uses a different path for the instantiation.

It looks like instantiate had the `-p` option to define a path but it seems that they removed it.

I installed chaincode with this commannd:

```
peer chaincode install -n cc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/cc/
```

Comment: Can you paste the command you used to package / install the chaincode?

Comment: @GariSingh added the command for installation

Comment: So I removed the -l node from the instantiate command and copied the content from fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/node to my cc directory and changed the content of the example chaincode to my chaincode and it worked. I first thought there is some rights issue but both files seemed to have the same rights. I'm still not sure what the issue was but it is fixed for now.